# How do i load div's besides each other

Tags: html, css, image, title

Im working on a html newsletter for my company and encountered a problem here.
Now i wrote some code, to get articles from our page's rss feed to the newsletter like title, thumbnail and summary.

```
<div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-6 col-md-3" >
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <!--#image name="image" #--><img src="http://cloud-files.crsend.com/img/noimage.png" style="width:300px; " /><!--#/image#-->

          <div class="caption" style="text-align:center;">
            <!--#html name="title" #--><h4>Thumbnail label</h4><!--#/html#-->
            <!--#html name="description" #--><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. 
            Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p><!--#/html#-->
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now what happens. I load the rss, select the article and it perfectly aligns on the left thumbnail, title and summary downwards. Now when i select a new Article it appears below but i want it to show on the right site. I know the solution when writing them directly in one code but those are getting loaded seperately.

P.S. Im very new to html and css so sorry if i made some plain mistakes.

Comment: can you post the css as well, ideally in a code snippet?

Comment: Sadly in this Newsletter-Creator im not allowed to use CSS external, just as inline code. So all css code is already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For email templates, it is better to use `<table>` rather than `<div>`. Email templates always need inline css and some of the properties like float are not supported. So it is difficult to construct a structure using `<div>` in email template. But it is easy with `<table>`

Comment: Thank you. I've read that point somewhere else also, what would be a example code for placing them besides each other?

Comment: put them in two separate <td> inside a single <tr>

Comment: there is no use in applying classes like col-xs-18, col-sm-6, col-md-3 etc. Email templates will not support external css or styles written in header

Comment: Cheers @MilosPre